# How to add Order Direction to @Query HQL. (ASC/DESC)

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

I have working HQL-code:

```
@Query("SELECT prod FROM Product as prod ORDER BY prod.rating ASC")
    List<Product> findProductsByRatingASC();
```

But I need to get list of products sorted by rating (in descending or ascending order).

I need something like:

```
@Query("SELECT prod FROM Product as prod ORDER BY prod.rating ?1")
    List<Product> findProductsByRating(String orderDir);
```

Where orderDir could be `ASC` or `DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely under the hood the `@Query` is just implemented using a prepared statement.  It is not possible to use a bind parameter to control the direction of an `ORDER BY` clause.  One workaround here would be to just maintain two separate queries, one for each sort direction:

```
@Query("SELECT prod FROM Product as prod ORDER BY prod.rating")
List<Product> findProductsByRatingASC();

@Query("SELECT prod FROM Product as prod ORDER BY prod.rating DESC")
List<Product> findProductsByRatingDESC();
```

Then, in your application code, check the incoming sort direction and call the appropriate method, e.g.

```
String order = "ASC";
if ("ASC".equals(order))  {
    findProductsByRatingASC();
}
else {
    findProductsByRatingDESC();
}
```

Comment: Yeah... that is good answer... But are there any other way of adding that query to the string and after place intro query?...

Comment: No, not as far as I know.  By the way, even if Hibernate were to accept your query, it would generate something like: `SELECT prod FROM Product as prod ORDER BY prod.rating 'ASC'` ... note carefully what has happened; the sort order now appears as a string literal.